# Proving Euler's product form of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, riemann-zeta

I was looking at Euler's product form for the Riemann zeta function, which I think is very cool. I thought I would have a go at proving it before looking at any proofs online. My training is in mathematical physics, I didn't take any courses on analysis in my undergrad and I'm trying to learn some.

Here is my proof;

Replace each factor in the product using the geometric series, $$\prod_{p \mathrm{prime}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \prod_{p \mathrm{prime}}\left( \sum_{r_p=0}^\infty( p^{-s})^{r_p}\right).$$
Note that $p^{-s} < 1$ for all $p$ and all $s>0$, so we know that each series converges.

Then distribute the product over the sums $$
\prod_{p \mathrm{prime}}\left( \sum_{r_p=0}^\infty( p^{-s})^{r_p}\right)=
\lim_{q\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}^q}
\prod_{p \mathrm{prime}<q} ( p^{-s})^{r_p}.$$

Now rearrange using power laws,
$$\lim_{q\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}^q}
\prod_{p \mathrm{prime}<q} ( p^{-s})^{r_p} = \lim_{q\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}^q}
\left(\prod_{p \mathrm{prime}<q} p^{r_p} \right)^{-s}.$$

Finally note that by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic this sum goes over all natural numbers written in terms of their prime factorisation, and hence
$$\lim_{q\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r\in\mathbb{N}^q}
\left(\prod_{p \mathrm{prime} <q} p^{r_p} \right)^{-s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}.$$

So I wanted to know, what would I need to justify for this proof to be rigours? It seems to me that the geometric series, power law rearrangement and fundamental theorem of arithmetic steps are all clear. The distributive step works for a finite product of finite sums, and it's intuitive to me that this would work for this infinite product of infinite sums, although this would require taking infinitely many limits. Is there any problem with doing this?

There is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function) on proving that these two forms of the Riemann zeta function are equivalent. The first proof due to Euler using the sieve of Eratosthenes is clearly inspired and beautiful.

The second proof is similar to my proof, but it follows a slightly different reasoning which bounds the difference between the two forms for the zeta function for a finite number of primes. This proof is more similar to the kind of arguments for proofs involving sequences and series that I have seen when looking through introductory courses on analysis. Is there some reason why proofs like this seem to be preferred?

The proof I've given appears to me to be more direct because it only rearranges the expression at each step, in a kind of roughly algorithmic way. I wouldn't have thought to myself to try and bound the absolute value for the difference for a finite number of factors, this requires introducing something new so seems less intuitive to me. Maybe this is because I have not spent enough time reading analysis courses yet.

Comment: Great question. Providing justifications for these and other infinite product manipulations was one of the main early motivations of analysis, particularly complex analysis. Most intuition of finite sums and products does not extend in any useful or general way to *all* infinite series and all products, but rigorization in specific cases often requires only an understanding of why a particular series or product development converges in a sense that some general theorem applies to. Have you read, or do you have access to, any textbooks? (Mentioning them allows for responses that refer to them.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I've learnt that I need to be careful about extending my intuition to infinite cases. I have a copy of Abbott that I haven't yet spend much time with. I've tried reading some different pdf lecture notes on analysis over the years and always found it to be a bit impenetrable, so I'm now trying to start with interesting examples, I thought that might help with motivation

Comment: All you need is that everything converges absolutely to rearrange everything as you did and get your result. Complex analysis is irrelevant here.

Comment: I realised I forgot to tag you in my previous comment, @leslietownes